# How to conditionally format multiple columns and specific rows in reactable table?

Tags: r, reactable

I have some example data below where I'm trying to conditionally format all numeric columns in my `reactable` table but only for row 1. For example, I'd like to use a traffic light system and assign the cell backgrounds in row 1 as green, red or orange if the value is more than that in row 2, within 10% of row 2 or more than 10% below the values in row 2, respectively.

```
library(reactable)

set.seed(1)
name <- c("Player A", "Player B", "Team")
var1 <- rnorm(3, 1000, 200)
var2 <- rnorm(3, 1000, 200)
var3 <- rnorm(3, 1000, 200)

d <- data.frame(name, var1, var2, var3)

reactable(d,
          defaultColDef = colDef(
            align = "center",
            format = colFormat(digits = 1)
          )
          )
```

I'm familiar with something like the below code, but I'm not sure how I can apply something like this to only specific rows and for multiple columns without repeating the function several times in `colDef()`.

```
reactable(sleep[1:6, ], columns = list(
  extra = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
      if (value > 0) {
        color <- "#008000"
      } else if (value < 0) {
        color <- "#e00000"
      } else {
        color <- "#777"
      }
      list(color = color, fontWeight = "bold")
    }
  )
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option to achieve your desired result which uses the row `index` passed to the style function as a second argument to access the value of the successor row. Additionally I use `lapply` to create the `colDef`s for a list of column names.

```
library(reactable)

style_fun <- function(.data, colname) {
  function(value, index) {
    if (index < 2) {
      successor_value <- .data[[colname]][index + 1]
      if (value > successor_value) {
        color <- "#008000"
      } else if (value >= .9 * successor_value) {
        color <- "orange"
      } else if (value < .9 * successor_value) {
        color <- "#e00000"
      } else {
        color <- "#777"
      }
      return(
        list(color = color, fontWeight = "bold")
      )
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  }
}

cols <- names(d)[-1]
col_defs <- lapply(
  cols, function(x)
  colDef(
    style = style_fun(d, x)
  )
) 
names(col_defs) <- cols

reactable(d,
  defaultColDef = colDef(
    align = "center",
    format = colFormat(digits = 1)
  ),
  columns = col_defs
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @stefan. This looks great. However, when I copy your code and run the `lapply()` call on `col_defs` I'm getting an error stating **Error: unexpected ')' in ")" setNames(cols) Error in setNames(cols) : argument "nm" is missing, with no default.** I'm not too familiar with `lapply()` so what could I be missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Hm. Weird. Just checked and works fine. The `lapply` is not causing the issue. it's the `setNames` part. I just made an edit and have rewritten using `names()` and without using the native pipe.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks, @stefan. The small edit worked perfectly.